# Changing TTY font to a non-default font

Tags: linux, console, fonts, tty

I found two ways to change the TTY font:

1. dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
2. editing /etc/default/console-setup

Either way I'm limited to the fonts in /usr/share/consolefonts (I'm using Debian).

- How do I install new console fonts?
- What are the requirements for this kind of font?
- ... in particular: would it be possible to use Anonymous Pro as console font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing [FbTerm](https://code.google.com/p/fbterm/) was what I went with to get nice fonts in my CLI environment. It's a frame buffer terminal emulator (so no need for X org) that supports nice rendering of the same kinds of fonts you would use in a GUI.

Comment: Have you seen fbterm behavior like this before? http://superuser.com/questions/892028/fbterm-expected-behavior-at-launch

Answer (score 2):

The PSF in the name of the files in `/etc/share/consolefonts` comes from PC Screen Fonts. Those are fixed width fonts that can be generated from bitmaps using
[psftools](http://www.seasip.info/Unix/PSF/), font2psf or [nafe](http://nafe.sourceforge.net/).

You can try if [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/) can convert your Anymous Pro, if not you could render all characters of that font at res 8x16 on an image and cut the individual characters out of that in a format `psftools` etc. understands.